# Why does CALayer not maintain its contents?

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I'm using CALayers to display a couple images. I do so by creating the layer and setting its contents property to a CGImageRef. I do not set a delegate on my CALayer.

The layer displays fine, but when another layer moves on top of the first layer, the lower layer's contents are "erased." I'm assuming the CALayer is calling the default delegate and drawing nothing. How do I make my CALayer persist its contents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The lower layer should not be erased by adding a new layer on top. My guess is that the lower layer is being covered (and thus obscured) by the layer you've added. Try making the new layer smaller than the original layer as a test.

Note that if you call certain methods like setNeedsDisplay on a layer, it WILL cause the layer  to discard it's contents.

Do you have any code that might be forcing the layer to redraw? (Like calling setNeedsDisplay, as mentioned above.) That would cause the symptom you are seeing.